# How to quickly (and elegantly) iterate between time series objects `ts` and date frames in R for ggplot2 plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am seeking guidance on how to quickly iterate between time series objects and date frames in R so that I plot in `ggplot2`, but allow for general analysis of the time series as `ts()`.

For example, the following feels very clunky:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)

AP <- AirPassengers
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(time(AP)), Y=as.matrix(AP))

ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(month(date)), y=Y)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Further, I loose (?) the ability to utilize `ggplot2::scale_x_date` this way?

**The essence of the question**: how can I quickly plot the result of the graph in the code **with  `ggplot2`** and ideally with month labels for the x-axis while *hopefully* jumping through fewer hoops?

I realize I could use:

```
boxplot(AP ~ cycle(AP))
```

But I would like to use `ggplot2` for greater flexibility.

Comment: I'm getting some errors while running your code. Are you sure `AP` supposed to be converted to `Date` class?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I apologize, forgot the `library(forecast)` package dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems to work.

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
AP <- AirPassengers
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(time(AP)), Y=as.matrix(AP))
ggplot(df)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=format(date,"%m"),y=Y))+
  scale_x_discrete("",labels=unique(format(df$date,"%b")))
```

[image]